# Can't install MinGW for Clion

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, mingw-w64, clion

Recently I installed Clion, but couldn't compile even "Hello World" application. 
I install MinGW compiller separately, but when I try to compile "Hello world" app I have next errors:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:45:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cwchar:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Alexandr\ClionProjects\untitled2\main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:67:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW iswalnum(wint_t);
 ^
...........
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:76:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW iswprint(wint_t);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:77:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW iswpunct(wint_t);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:80:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW iswxdigit(wint_t);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:84:29: error: expected initializer before 'iswblank'
 int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW iswblank (wint_t);
                             ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:90:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW towlower (wint_t);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:91:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW towupper (wint_t);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:93:1: error: '_CRTIMP' does not name a type
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW isleadbyte (int);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:157:33: error: expected initializer before 'towctrans'
 wint_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  towctrans(wint_t, wctrans_t);
                                 ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:158:35: error: expected initializer before 'wctrans'
 wctrans_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW wctrans(const char*);
                                   ^
c:\mingw\include\wctype.h:159:34: error: expected initializer before 'wctype'
 wctype_t __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW wctype(const char*);
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just installed a fresh copy of MingW correctly and selected a lot of package to install, after that you install CLion 1.1.1 and set the path to c:\MingW\bin to your environment variable PATH

Inslall link for MingW: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

I created a hello project and compiled it, all things works correctly

Here is the result of execution of hello world and there is no compiler problem

> If there is a path problem, as I had, you have to de-install and install CLion to recognize your path as I did

[image]

Tested under windows 7

Comment: They have an installer which downloads from sourceforge the selected MinGW packages.

Comment: The question is tagged with mingw-w64, are you sure this creates a 64-bit executable?

Comment: For me `mingw32-base` and `mingw32-gcc-g++` was sufficient to make it work